# A Western follower of Sanatan Dharma does have a Varna Dharma?

Tags: astrology, manu-smriti, birth, varnashrama

According to jyotish Kundali myself too I have a Dharma Varna. I want to know if is evaluable, if is true and finally if is important for a western born person in order to be accepted by any Hindu Sanatani Community.

---

Perfectioning my requirement as per Stack Exchange community requests:

Factual reasons of asking this: In India someone still trust in Varna birth Dharma as this will be the causative of what one can do as Aartha to benefit the Dharma society. E.g. Ksathrya will be warrior, Brahmin will be Dharma Teachers and Custody of Knowledge etc

Someone else do reject this thing. So Indian people online in other contexts and in real meetings told me.

No one explained me how it is definitely the thing.

Sources: Indian people who talked to me.

This question is not opinion-based for me because my wish is to be answered with current Laws of India Hindu societies.

Thank you

Comment: This answer is applicable: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16918/4732

Comment: And this is probably a duplicate of: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30080/which-varnas-do-they-belong-to/30082#30082

Comment: @Rickross jyotish of me says I am a Brahmin. Could it be?

Comment: @Rickross the first link does not help. I m not buddhist. The second link helps more. Yet Read my previous comment and let me know please. Thank you

Comment: @Rickross no it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Even though you are not a Buddhist that line of answering will work for your question. That's why suggested that answer. Your astrological varna is Brahmin that shows your innate nature. And it appears to me that you are a seeker of knowledge with a good understanding of Dharma.

Comment: @Rickross yes it is since my childhood long till now. Your answers are the most rich in Sanskrit received from me. Please let me know if you can send some Sanskrit teacher to me, online until now, hopefully I will finish my reincarnation of now in Bharat somewhere. Om Nama Shivaya

Comment: I don't know about any online Sanskrit teacher. But you can ask in [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism). They might be able to help you.

Comment: Danyawaad mere mitra @Rickross Ji.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swami Vivekananda considered the astrolgical Varna to be the true Varna.

> Every Hindu knows that astrologers try to fix the caste of every boy
> or girl as soon as he or she is born. **That is the real caste** — the
> individuality, and Jyotisha (astrology) recognises that. And we can
> only rise by giving it full sway again. This variety does not mean
> inequality, nor any special privilege.

**The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 4, Writings Prose, A Plan of Work for India (Written to Justice Sir Subrahmanya Iyer from Chicago, 3rd Jan., 1895.)**

Nowadays even born Hindus find it impossible to follow Varna Dharma. I am posting Swami Tapasyananda's discussion of this issue.

> A great doctrine of the social philosophy of ancient India, regarding
> the fourfold class system, is here propounded. There has been no
> doctrine so much misapplied, misunderstood and misrepresented as this
> doctrine. The four Varnas of Brahmana, Ksatriyas, Vaisyas and Sudras
> are today and for a long time past, understood as four hereditary
> castes. But the Varnas, as understood by the best Indian thinkers, are
> not castes based on birth in particular groups, but character types
> based on the domination of the Sattvika, Rajasika and Tamasika
> elements entering into the constitution of their body-mind, and this
> is determined by their evolution in their past lives. At least such is
> the Gita view. To have identified character types with endogamous
> castes is nothing but an aberration. …….
>
> These four character types are universal all the world over and the
> prosperity of a society will depend on the man of the right nature and
> character being put to the right type of duty. For the individuals
> also doing the duty that is natural to his psycho-physical
> constitution, is the way of higher evolution.

**Commentary on Gita 18.41 to 18.44 by Swami Tapasyananda in his English translation of Srimad Bagavad Gita**

> By being devoted to one's own natural duty, man attains to spiritual
> competency. Now hear how devotion to one's own natural duty generates
> spiritual competency.

**[Gita 18.45]**

> From whom all beings have emanated and by whom all this universe is
> pervaded - by worshiping Him through the dedicated performance of
> one's duty, man attains to spiritual competency.

**[Gita 18.46]**

> These two verses (18.45–46) of the Gita link man’s social duties with
> spiritual disciplines. By cultivating a special attitude towards work,
> work is turned into worship, and the distance between the shrine room
> and the work-spot disappears. This philosophy is based upon a
> fundamental faith that this world and the progress of life in it are
> all under the guidance of a Supreme Intelligence, who is the master of
> it all, and whose will is expressed in all its movements. If man has
> got this faith, man ceases to be self-centered. He comes to view
> himself as a worker of God, and all that he does comes to be done with
> a sense of dedication to Him. Such work accrues to one according to
> one’s nature and is done with a spirit of dedication, is called
> Svadharma, one’s natural duty. ………
>
> A natural objection to this way of understanding Caturvarnyas is that
> all commentators understood the four Varnas as endogamous groups
> called castes and the ‘natural duty’ (Svadharma) of theirs as the
> profession that was traditionally and scripturally alloted to those
> groups under the four distinctive names. Such interpretations of the
> Gita were given at a time when these endogamous groups were a
> recognised feature of Indian society, and thinkers considered birth in
> a group as tantamount to character type. The mistake of such
> identification was obvious to many thinkers of the past. So many of
> them have made amends by admitting that if great disparity in quality
> is found in the actual quality of a Ksatriya with the traditionally
> ascribed qualities, he can become a Brahmana. But all rationality
> seems to have been neutralised by the very strong prejudice in favour
> of endogamy.
>
> …………………………..
>
> But what the Lord speaks of here as Caturvarnya should never be
> identified with castes, because the Varna is said to be solely
> dependent on character formed by the Gunas of Prakriti. It is only an
> ideal grouping based on psycological principle and not on rigid
> hereditary basis.
>
> Besides the Gita is a universal Gospel addressed to all mankind, for
> all time, and not merely to the Indian society of a particular age. In
> no part of the world except in India, caste system strictly based on
> birth seems to have existed. Loose classes there have been, but no
> rigid castes with unchangeable duties and occupations ………. So the old
> commentators have done great injustice to Sri Krshna in watering down
> the significance of his message as relevant only to members of the
> rigid Indian social system.,,,,

**Commentary on Gita 18.45–46 by Swami Tapasyananda in his English translation of Srimad Bhagavad Gita.**

> One's own duty, even if without excellence (i.e. inferior in the scale
> of worldly values)is more meritorious spiritually than the apparently
> well-performed duty of another. For no sin is incurred by one doing
> works ordained according to one's nature.

**[Gita 18.47]**

> This verse was interpreted by old commentators as jobs ascribed to
> particular castes. This verse is interpreted differently by those who
> follow Vivekananda's psychological explanation of Varna.
>
> These verses, which were easy for our ancients to understand, pose
> great difficulty for us today. So long as Varna was identified with
> the endogamous caste, and valid texts ascribed particular works to
> each caste it was easy to find out one's Svadharma, and if one had a
> will, to perform it too. That a priest's son should be a priest, a
> soldier's son a soldier, a merchant's son a merchant, an
> agriculturist's son an agriculturist, a serf's son a serf - is an
> arrangement that could be practised to some extent in the old feudal
> society when educational opportunities were restricted, when there was
> no choice in following professions, when social contacts were limited,
> and when the validity of the system was accepted by the people in
> general. But today such an idea of Svadharma hereditarily determined,
> is impossible of practice. Society and professions have become
> competitive. The imparting of education without any restriction
> imposed by caste, has helped the shuffling of professional abilities
> among all members of society, setting aside hereditary factors. So it
> has become honourable for any one to follow any profession, and the
> determination of Svadharma based on birth as in a caste based economy,
> has become impractical and impossible, and also undesirable. In a
> democratic society, the same kind of education is open to all, and
> every one is eligible, according to one's qualification and capacity,
> to positions of power, prestige and high income. In these days of
> national armies every able-bodied citizen has the eligibility to be
> recruited - he may even be conscripted - in the armed forces of the
> country. In such a milieu, if the Gita idea of Svadharma is accepted
> as caste based, as it was understood a few generations back, and as it
> used to be interpreted by old commentators, then it has become
> thoroughly outmoded and will be rejected by every section of society
> in India and outside.
>
> **But as already pointed out, the wording of the Gita about Caturvarnya,
> except as interpreted by old commentators, does not mean endogamous
> castes, but the four psychological types. If this is accepted,
> Svadharma would mean only work that springs out of one's own nature
> and therefore adapted to one's natural development. But how to
> recognise these types and how to provide them with work suited to
> their nature - is a problem that cannot be solved. We have to leave
> work based on psychological type as an ideal arrangement in a more
> rationally organised society of the future. There is no other way
> today but to understand Svadharma as the duty devolving on oneself in
> society, inclusive of the profession one follows. If that is done well
> with God in view, and not merely for remuneration or with a worldly
> master in view, then one may be said to follow Svadharma.**

**Commentary on Gita 18.47 by Swami Tapasyananda in his English translation of Srimad Bhagavad Gita.**

Comment: Thank you very much for this complete answer @Pradip Gangopadhyay

Answer (score 1):

Your Varna refers to your ancestral profession - hardly anyone follows an ancestral profession and everyone is free to choose their own profession or vocation - none of which are of any interest to “Sanatana Dharma” except perhaps the priestly profession. There is no central authority or induction committee, or application office or process that will allocate a vocation (Varna) to you and provide you with an ID card . Sanatana Dharma is fellowship of seekers which you can join in spirit through reading and adopting philosophy and values and practices or you can join a study or practice group.

Comment: Dhanyawaad, I mean Thank You. I trust in your answer. @Sethu Srivatsa Koduru

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation @hindustudent I suggest you to start studying Vedanta or works of Saints who teach Vedanta like Swami Sivananda,Swami Vivekananda etc

Comment: Ji yes! I am a follower of Swami Sivananda Saraswati since years. I like Divine Life Society purposes .I discovered all online by "chance" let us say. What I miss is practical knowledge of being in India and guided by some teachers in real. @Sethu Srivatsa Koduru I am searching good evaluable Sanaatani Indian friends. In my Profile page I left my contacts. Thank you so much for your encouragement. My path started some years ago. It is time for me to go to India I feel. I wish to go there soon. I am happy that you also like Sivananda Swami Ji. Many more indian I have met were into Vivekananda.

Comment: <<What I miss is practical knowledge of being in India and guided by some teachers in real.>>
You should have listened to Swami Sarwapriyananda, Jay Lakhani and Swami Samparananda talks here : https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOsVQYiDSaj4F9t7ZnAOkV_gIPh_IPy6Q

Comment: It is never too late and I want to live my life in India like a Hindu by the way with face to face people to guide me. That was my meaning. Swami Sivananda is My preferencial Swami, along with Ramakrishnan mission, Sannyasini close to Vivekananda teachings to some extents very respectful.  Thank you for helping me with new links I am going to check and learn @Sethu Srivatsa Koduru

Comment: @hindustudent-TheWhiteHindu Do search Swami Sarwapriyananda and Jay Lakhani Vedios on Youtube :)

Comment: "Your Varna refers to your ancestral profession" you confuse VARNA with JATI. This is common but incorrect. This is such false that you must know a "brahman" born before he receives a religious initiation (about his 7-8 years old) is a shudra. This is not based on the born, this based on the religious degree of education you received. In the reality the twice-born received an education on Holy Vedas, others received an education on puranas (inferior texts).