# How are people from different countries put into the varna system

Tags: varna

1). Who was the first human couple in hinduism from which the population began, what were their varna ,and how did other varna originate from them? Since in vedas god says that he created the Varna’s from his different body part eg.Brahmins from head.

2).If varna system is to be true, what category do africans, europeans,Hispanics,Chinese,all other countries speaking different language fall into?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3898/4732

Comment: Relevant answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16918/4732

Comment: Another related post (basically asking the same thing in different words) - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/30080/4732